# Can you auto generate step definitions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, specflow

I have currently created a noddy google search program as Gherkin Feature file using Specflow in Visual Studio Community.  Using Visual Studio (or community) you have the option to right click and auto generate the step definition skeleton.

Does anyone know if you can also auto generate when in Visual Studio Code (or is there a plugin to allow it)?  Initial investigation I don't get that option and trying to google for an answer was less than helpful

Comment: I was playing around with VS Code a little while back and ran into the same problem. I couldn't find an extension that did this.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved if anyone is interested.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RajUppadhyay.specflow-steps-definition-generator.  This add on does the trick.

@Greg Burghardt

Comment: If this really did answer your question, you can accept this as the answer to your question. Just click the check mark icon next to this answer.

Comment: You can also view the [SpecFlow installation guide for Visual Studio Code](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/vscode/vscode-specflow.html). I wonder if this plugin is listed?